# VS code doesn't detect UnityEngine.UI library - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

The issue is VS code doesn't see `UnityEngine.UI` library.

I had this issue before and I solved like it this:
*I changed the code editor in preferences to Visual Studio, regenerated files and launched c# project. On the start, vs created needed .csproj files and then I closed vs and changed it back to vs code and it workeed.*

However, now I am working on another project and I encountered same issue, I tried the method I described above but it didn't work.

Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Another project... on the same computer? I wonder if you're missing the Unity tools.

Comment: @Chuck  yes same pc, everything is the same. All necessary tools are present. Intellisense works fine.

Comment: You can disable packages in Unity, UI is one of those. You can verify if you have a reference in your *.sln.

If you are using asmdef you might need to link UnityEngine.UI.dll to your asmdef

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak could you tell me please how to link UnityEngine.UI.dll to my asmdef , and also I am not sure  if I use it. How can I check it I do? Regarding the first part, I can't uninstall UI package because Text Mesh Pro and URP relies on it.

Comment: I had the exact same issue after updating one of my project from 2020.3.15 to 2020.3.19 (lts)

Answer (score 0):

So, after days of tinkering and trying different solutions I found on the internet I finally found out how to solve it (all by myself).

Switch to VS and make sure it detects the `UnityEngine.UI` library. Then don't close VS, switch to VS Code, don't hit "regenerate files", launch c# project, enjoy!

Comment: This did work for me. Unfortunately it seems I need to do this everytime I open project. (if I switch back to choose vscode instead visual studio as the external tool). But good to have a workaround

Comment: @shrekshao I found a permanent solution. Just use Rider. It's waaay better and without cancerous glitches.

Answer (score 0):

These steps covered several possible issues:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70977258/6046022

(just an overview, follow the link for the complete steps)

1. downgrade VSC package
2. re-install Unity UI
3. regenerate files

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was driving me crazy. Tried a 100 ways.

**What helped for me in the end:**

1. Go into package manager
2. Select the Unity registry
3. Search for "Visual Studio Code Editor"
4. Update it.
5. I restarted unity and vscode, and it just worked :)

Hope this helps someone!